# Class that has a list of itself as a property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following class and wondered if it is allowed?

```
     public class Node
     {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public string ParentNodeId { get; set; }

        public List<Node> TargetNodes { get; set; }
     }
```

The code compiles and even works but I am getting stack errors where I shouldn't be getting stack errors and wondered if it is because of my TargetNodes property? Should I create a new class for TargetNodes?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Can you please add code producing stack errors? And errors also. As for you questions - 1) yes, it is allowed and not an unusual practice 2) it depends on your usecase.

Comment: If this is allowed and not an unusual practice then my stack error must be unrelated.

I undid all my changes regarding TargetNodes and reverted to what was working, which was a string list of TargetIds instead of the actual node. I will try again tomorrow and come back with the stack errors and where the code fails. Maybe it's just unrelated and I made a mistake somewhere else. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The problem was unrelated. I realised the function I was using to populate the nodes was calling itself and creating endless nodes in the list finding new targets and entering a loop.